# Filter grouped row by highest occurrence of string with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on collapsing down a transcriptomics dataset from transcript to gene level for a downstream analysis. Within this dataset, each row has a unique gene identifier (`qry_gene_id`) and each `qry_gene_id` can have multiple `qry_transcript_ids`. I would like to filter the dataset to select the `qry_transcript_id` from each `qry_gene_id` that has the greatest number of `go_id` (GO:XXXXXXX). The `go_id` column is a list of `go_id`s separated by `","`.

Here is a subset my data:

```
structure(list(qry_transcript_id = c("TU22", "TU20", "TU27", 
"TU29", "TU25", "TU26", "TU28", "TU31", "TU24", "TU30"), go_id = c(NA, 
NA, "GO:0004672,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0006468", "GO:0005003,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005887,GO:0006468,GO:0007169", 
"GO:0005003,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005887,GO:0006468,GO:0007169", 
"GO:0005003,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005887,GO:0006468,GO:0007169", 
"GO:0005003,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005887,GO:0006468,GO:0007169", 
"GO:0005003,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005887,GO:0006468,GO:0007169", 
"GO:0005003,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005887,GO:0006468,GO:0007169", 
"GO:0005003,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005887,GO:0006468,GO:0007169"
), ref_gene_id = c("LOC108906571", "LOC108906589", "LOC108906588", 
"LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", 
"LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", "LOC108906588"), qry_gene_id = c("G10", 
"G9", "G12", "G12", "G12", "G12", "G12", "G12", "G12", "G12"), 
    ref_gene_name = c("uncharacterized LOC108906571", "uncharacterized LOC108906589", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B"
    ), gene_annotation = c("refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq"
    ), ref_transcript_id = c("XM_018709871.1", "XM_018709894.2", 
    "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", 
    "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1"
    ), ref_transcript_name = c("uncharacterized LOC108906571", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108906589", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", 
    "ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2"), class_code = c("i", 
    "k", "j", "j", "=", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j")), row.names = 21:30, class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see for `qry_gene_id` = G12, the first transcript is missing a couple of GO ids. I want to make sure that my filter selects a transcript that has the full compliment of GO ids.

However, I'm stuck on how to filter this appropriately. Here's where I'm at.

```
test_data <- test_data %>% group_by(qry_gene_id) %>% filter()
```

It seems logical to me that filtering by either 1) total length of that string (which I think should capture the longest list of GO terms) or 2) counting occurrences of a string (e.g. "GO") and selecting the ones with the highest count of "GO". Basically I want to end up not leaving out any of the GO terms associated with each gene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach to keep the rows with the highest count of "GO" in each group:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test_data %>% 
  mutate(go_count = str_count(go_id, "GO")) %>%
  group_by(qry_gene_id) %>% 
  slice_max(go_count)
```

See `?slice_max` in case you want to fine tune this, e.g., adjust what happens when there are ties. The default will keep all rows tied for the most occurrences of "GO" within a group.

You could also use something like `filter(which.max(nchar(go_id)))`, keeping the maximum number of characters.